# Symfony Elastic Bundle error

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

Hei, guys I just installed the elastic search bundle on my project, everything looks find till I use the

```
php app/console fos:elastica:populate
```

command and I get the following code:

```
Resetting app
 17/17 [============================] 100%
Populating app/professionalRefreshing app


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Notice: Array to string conversion
```

If I try to get all the information on my elastic, I'm able to see them all but when I try to work with it on my controller, I'm getting null values.

Any help?

Thanks

////// UPDATE

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: ...
    indexes:
        app: 
            types:
                professional:
                    properties:
                        name: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\Professional
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
```

Comment: It seems that you messed something with mapping so for example You're trying to index one-to-many property from Your entity as string field in ES.

Comment: @barat But now i'm just mapping the name property, and it's a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is by using elastic cloud 1.7 version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup Basic Bundle Configuration and Defining index types like below code?

port 9200 should be enable in your machine.

```
#app/config/config.yml
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        app: ~
```

---

```
fos_elastica:
indexes:
    app:
        types:
            user:
                properties:
                    username: ~
                    firstName: ~
                    lastName: ~
                    email: ~
```

Comment: Yes, im actualy using elastic cloud, and all seem okai, I edit my question with this code